# VBScript: XPath Query with multiple namespaces

Tags: xpath, vbscript

What `XPath` query should I use to get to the `GetLogisticsOfferDateResult` Node?
I have attached the vbscript that I'm using.
I suspect the problem has to do with the multiple namespaces in the document.  But how do I reference the second namespace in the XPath?

```
Dim responseXML
responseXML = '"<s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""><s:Body><GetLogisticsOfferDateResponse xmlns=""http://schneider-electric.com/OrderEntryService""><GetLogisticsOfferDateResult>2010-07-20</GetLogisticsOfferDateResult></GetLogisticsOfferDateResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>"'

Dim responseDoc
Set responseDoc = WScript.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
responseDoc.loadXML(responseXML)
responseDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'"
Dim requestedNode
'This node is not found
'Set requestedNode = responseDoc.selectSingleNode("//s:Envelope//s:Body//GetLogisticsOfferDateResponse//GetLogisticsOfferDateResult")

'This node is found
Set requestedNode = responseDoc.selectSingleNode("//s:Envelope//s:Body")
'This node is found
'Set requestedNode = responseDoc.selectSingleNode("//s:Envelope")

If requestedNode Is Nothing Then
    WScript.Echo "Node not found"
Else
    WScript.Echo requestedNode.text
End If

Set responseDoc = Nothing
Set LODateNode = Nothing
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out my setting of selectionNamespaces had to be as follows:

```
responseDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:sc='http://schneider-electric.com/OrderEntryService' xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'"
```

Then the XPath query had to be:

```
Set requestedNode = responseDoc.selectSingleNode("//s:Envelope//s:Body//sc:GetLogisticsOfferDateResponse//sc:GetLogisticsOfferDateResult")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined the default namespace of the document (`http://schneider-electric.com/OrderEntryService`) in your code.

```
responseDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' 'http://schneider-electric.com/OrderEntryService'"
```

You will either need to add it, or prefix the elements that belong to it with it.

Comment: OK I've edited the following line in my VBScript to read:
responseDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns='http://schneider-electric.com/OrderEntryService/' xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'"

yet the call to the following line does not return a node:
Set requestedNode = responseDoc.selectSingleNode("//s:Envelope//s:Body//GetLogisticsOfferDateResponse//GetLogisticsOfferDateResult")